# calling an environment variable in a ps-watcher config file

Tags: perl, environment-variables

I am trying to use [ps-watcher](http://ps-watcher.sourceforge.net/ps-watcher.html) to monitor my system and make sure a given number of worker threads are working on a task. If I hard code the number of workers into the config file for ps-watcher, it works great. However I would like the number of workers to be pulled from an environment variable named WORKERS. This seems simple, but has proven to be a pain.

Here's an example config file that works:

```
[myProg]
  trigger = $count<5
  action = /home/ubuntu/startWorkers.sh
```

I pulled the following from the man for ps-watcher:

> This parameter specifies the condition
>   on which a process action is fired.
>   The condition is evaluated with Perl
>   eval() and should therefore return
>   something which is equivalent to
>   ``true'' in a Perl expression.

Which makes me think I should use `$ENV{VARIABLE}` as I would in Perl. So I tried the following:

```
[myProg]
  trigger = $count<$ENV{WORKERS}
  action = /home/ubuntu/startWorkers.sh
```

to which my ps-watcher log recorded the following:

> Use of uninitialized value in
>   concatenation (.) or string at (eval
>   6) line 1 (#1)
>       (W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
>       defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
>       To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.
>       To help you figure out what was undefined, perl will try to tell you
>       the
>       name of the variable (if any) that was undefined. In some cases it cannot
>       do this, so it also tells you what operation you used the undefined value
>       in.  Note, however, that perl optimizes your program and the
>       operation displayed in the warning may not necessarily appear literally in your
>       program.  For example, "that $foo" is usually optimized into "that "
>       . $foo, and the warning will refer to the concatenation (.) operator,
>       even though there is no . in your program.

I'm at a bit of a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like this example gives hints... but I can't grok it: http://ps-watcher.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ps-watcher/ps-watcher/samples/port-watch.ini?view=markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the single quote idea, but also double-check that the variable is actually exported by doing a `print "$ENV{'WORKERS'}\n";` before the eval.  Perhaps you are not exporting the variable into the children.

Comment: Also do a print of $trigger or whatever you are evaluating to double-check the resulting perl code is what you want.

Comment: the pain I'm having is that this is a configuration file, not a proper Perl script... although it is being parsed by Perl. I wish I could throw debugging code in there and test it, but I can't. As I think about it, I suspect you are right about this being an export problem. But I'm not sure how to verify. I may have to start digging through the source for ps-watcher.

Comment: @JD Long: Then run `printenv > /tmp/x` in an evaluated context, or `ps axewww` while the program is running, to check for the environmental variable.

Comment: hey thanks. I slipped a printenv in there in ticks and it evaluated. And I can see that the environment variable is not being exported. Now to figure out why.

Comment: @JD Long: Please upvote and accept, then.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe single quotes around the environment variable?

```
$ENV{'WORKERS'};
```

Comment: I was expecting it to be something with escaping or quoting. Unfortunately the single quotes didn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The single quotes were needed, but I also had issues with the environment variable not being exported.